# What is faster: MotionEvent.getEventTime() or System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: android

I would like to measure the time elapsed between `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. Which of the methods is more efficient:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long msEventTime = event.getEventTime(); 

    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            msTouchDown = msEventTime;
            return;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            msTouchUp = msEventTime;
            duration = msTouchUp - msTouchDown;
            return;
    }
}
```

or this method

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long msEventTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            msTouchDown = msEventTime;
            return;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            msTouchUp = msEventTime;
            duration = msTouchUp - msTouchDown;
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are strictly interested in the time difference between events, rather than the time difference between calls to onTouchEvent then you should use the event timestamps.

In practice there will be just a few op-codes difference, and certainly negligible to the millisec result.  Do both methods at once and compare the timestamps and difference. They will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **MotionEvent.getEventTime()** seems to be the right approach in your context.
Also, it is supposed to be faster (although by very little time), since the call is reading the (already checked) time that has been associated to the motion event by the Android system, thus avoiding the additional system call and/or calculation.
As a bonus, the time is (by definition) more relevant to the measurement you're doing, due to it being the actual time when the touch event occurred.